# Using spacy to get rid of stopwords in pandas series

Tags: python, nlp, data-science, text-mining, spacy

I had been trying to get rid of stopwords using spacy library.

**Code**

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

nlp= spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

**my_series:**

```
my_series

0        this laptop sits at just over 4 stars while so...
1        i ordered this monitor because i wanted to mak...
2        this monitor is a great deal for the price and...
3        bought this for the height adjustment. the swi...
4        worked for a month and then it died. after 5 c...
                               ...                        
30618                                           great deal
30619                                      pour le travail
30620                                         business use
30621                                            good size
30622    pour mon ordinateur.plus grande image.vraiment...
Name: text_body, Length: 30623, dtype: object
```

**Tokenize**

```
s_tokenized=my_series.apply(lambda x: nlp(x))
```

**Remove stopwords**

```
all_stopwords = nlp.Defaults.stop_words
filtered_text=s_tokenized.apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w in all_stopwords])
filtered_text

0        [this, laptop, sits, at, just, over, 4, stars,...
1        [i, ordered, this, monitor, because, i, wanted...
2        [this, monitor, is, a, great, deal, for, the, ...
3        [bought, this, for, the, height, adjustment, ....
4        [worked, for, a, month, and, then, it, died, ....
                               ...                        
30618                                        [great, deal]
30619                                  [pour, le, travail]
30620                                      [business, use]
30621                                         [good, size]
30622    [pour, mon, ordinateur.plus, grande, image.vra...
Name: text_body, Length: 30623, dtype: object
```

tokenize seems to be working fine but removing stopwords does not seems to remove any word at all nor raising any errors. Is there something I miss or did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with this line:

```
filtered_text=s_tokenized.apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w in all_stopwords])
```

correct it to:

```
filtered_text=s_tokenized.apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w.text in all_stopwords])
```

and you're fine to go:

```py
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
s_tokenized = my_series.apply(nlp)
all_stopwords = nlp.Defaults.stop_words
filtered_text=s_tokenized.apply(lambda x: [w for w in x if not w.text in all_stopwords])
filtered_text
0      [laptop, sits, 4, stars]
1    [ordered, monitor, wanted]
dtype: object
```

Note, you do not need pandas Series to hold your data. Just string or list of strings is enough. The Spacy way of doing the same, that will scale for even out of memory data is:

```
import spacy
nlp=spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
texts = ["this laptop sits at just over 4 stars while", "i ordered this monitor because i wanted"]
docs = nlp.pipe(texts)
filtered_text= []
for doc in docs:
#     yield [tok for tok in doc if not tok.is_stop]
    filtered_text.append([tok for tok in doc if not tok.is_stop])
print(filtered_text)

[[laptop, sits, 4, stars], [ordered, monitor, wanted]]
```